# How to create ASP.NET MVC 5 Web Application in Visual Studio Community 2013?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to start an MVC 5 project after installing a fresh installation of Visual Studio Community 2013 but when I go to

> New Project > Templates > Visual C# > Web > Version2012

all I see in the middle pane is ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application. Does anyone have any ideas why I do not have ASP.NET MVC 5 Web Application?

I have .NET Framework 4.5.1 selected.

Comment: Use NUGET to get the MVC 5 packages.

Comment: Select `ASP.NET Web Application` from the Visual C# templates. After that you'll be given the option to select MVC.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have the ASP.NET Web Application option so I will try NUGET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to uninstall all old versions of Visual Studio and then repair the Community version and then the template has miraculously appeared, thanks to everyone who posted.

Answer (score 7):

In Visual Studio 2013, you need to select **ASP.Net Web Application**.

Then you can select what type of Web Application in next step.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I dont see this window, mine is different as it does not have the Change Authentication button nor the Microsoft Azure panel.

Answer (score 2):

You must choose New Project > Templates > Visual C# > Web > ASP.NET Web Application and then you will be able to choose MVC between the core references WebForms, MVC and WebAPI

Answer (score 2):

They merged all the Web Applications into one project type.  Select `ASP.NET Web Application` then in the next menu, click MVC to create a new MVC 5 project.

A description of the ASP.NET Web Application project can be found [here](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Thanks but I dont have the ASP.NET Web Application option, I have been looking for it for at least 10 minutes..

Comment: when you installed visual studio did you check the `Web Development tools`?

Comment: the web development tools option was not available unfortunately.