# Using Asp.net mvc in Visual studio 2015 Enterprise

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I do not have asp.net mvc project when i go to the

```
File -> New -> Website -> Templates -> Visual C#
```

I have seen [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/696518/Using-ASP-NET-MVC-within-Visual-Studio), and tried to follow it.

But when I try to install [this](https://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx/getinstaller/WebNode11Pack.appids)

It complains that cannot find such product

.
At the same time i am sure that i have installed **Microsoft Asp.net MVC 4**

**So how can i use aps.net mvc in vs 2015 Enterprise?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create ASP.NET MVC 5 Web Application in Visual Studio Community 2013?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27569307/how-to-create-asp-net-mvc-5-web-application-in-visual-studio-community-2013)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2015, MVC Applications have been consolidated into ASP.NET Web Applications as opposed to Web Sites or any other previous classification.

You'll just need to access them through **File > New > Project > Visual C# > Web > ASP.NET Web Application** and then select MVC from the dialog that appears :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

> File -> New - > Project -> Visual c# - > ASP.NET Web application